# How to add the google ad conversion tracking code into the thank you page

Tags: plugins, scripts

How to add the google ad conversion tracking code into the thank you page (Contact form7 - Redirected thank you page)  in WordPress. I’ve tried to place the tracking code on this specific page but instead, the code is placed on every page of the website.

Comment: May I know how have you tried to add the code in that specific page?

Comment: Tried to paste code through header.php,

Comment: Have you defined the condition to check if the page is thank-you page?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add conditional code like this:

```
<?php if (is_page ('thank-you')){ ?>

  // script goes here

<?php } ?>
```

NOTE: Replace the thank-you with your page slug or you can even replace it with the page ID and add your tracking code just below `//script goes here`.

One more way is to do it via plugin, here is a link to such plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/oh-add-script-header-footer/